# Using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh to get all eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to get all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a particular real symmetric matrix. This is obviously possible with `numpy.linalg.eigh`, however, this matrix has a particular sparse structure which allows linear scaling dot-product with a vector. For this reason, I would like to use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh`, which allows for a `LinearOperator` in place of the input array, and use of the implicitly restarted Lanczos method.

My problem is that `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh` does not allow calculation of all eigenvalues and eigenvectors (i.e. `k=n`), and the rank of my input matrix is typically equal to `n`. Is there any way to get around this, or does any other function allow similar functionality?